# Flask add_url_rule with options throws unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use Flask Blueprints to add a dynamic run time route. I'm calling `add_url_rule()` and passing some data to the view.

```
def add_special_route(route_url, data):
    myblueprint.add_url_rule(route_url, view_func=my_special_view_function, specialparameter=data)

def my_special_view_function(specialparameter):
    return specialparameter.some_string_x
```

The compiler doesn't like specialparameter.  The error is `unexpected keyword argument`. I was expecting it to go into the **options kwargs on add_url_rule.

I've looked at the docs for examples that use **options.  Not much.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to add the rule with `specialparameter` set as a default value (using `data`)?

Comment: Yes exactly -- set specialparameter's default value to be data

Comment: You're mistaking use of option. According to doc "The options to be forwarded to the underlying Rule object. A change to Werkzeug is handling of method options. methods is a list of methods this rule should be limited to (GET, POST etc.)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default parameters for a view should be passed in in a dictionary with the `defaults` keyword argument:

```
def add_special_route(route_url, data):
    myblueprint.add_url_rule(
        route_url, view_func=my_special_view_function,
        defaults={'specialparameter': data})
```

See the [*URL Route Registrations* documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations).