# Flask `add_url_rule` options argument doesn't add additional keyword options

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass additional keyword options to a function registered with Flask's `add_url_rule`. Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
import flask
APP = flask.Flask(__name__)
APP.add_url_rule('/', 'get_all', routes.get_all, class_name='Entity')
```

This is the error I'm receiving.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "src/main.py", line 118, in <module>
  class_name='Entity')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 64, in wrapper_func
  return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1043, in add_url_rule
  rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_name'
```

Based on the documentation, i thought that any additional keyword parameters would be included in the function call `routes.get_all` under the `options` parameter. This does not seem to be the case.

This is similar to but not the same as [Flask add_url_rule with options throws unexpected keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809215/flask-add-url-rule-with-options-throws-unexpected-keyword-argument).

Can someone please explain how to pass arbitrary parameters to the function linked by the `add_url_rule` Flask method?

Answer (score 2):

**options** – the options to be forwarded to the underlying Rule object. A change to Werkzeug is handling of method options. methods is a list of methods this rule should be limited to (GET, POST etc.). By default a rule just listens for GET (and implicitly HEAD). Starting with Flask 0.6, OPTIONS is implicitly added and handled by the standard request handling.

You can send method to this:

```
APP.add_url_rule('/', 'get_all', routes.get_all, methods=["POST", "POST", "PUT"])
```

Please see the implementation of this code: [add_url_rule](https://github.com/mhall1/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L939)

Also, you can send your options with `defaults` in a dict like [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/#method-views-for-apis).

Your params goes to `url_rule_class` function (see [this](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1d4448abe335741c61b3c8c5f99e1607a13f7e3d/flask/app.py#L1051)) :

```
rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
```

and now see this:

You can use any of this params as options, not anything else!

```
class werkzeug.routing.Rule(string, defaults=None, subdomain=None, methods=None, build_only=False, endpoint=None, strict_slashes=None, redirect_to=None, alias=False, host=None)
```

See [werkzeug.routing.Rule](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule)

Comment: So based on this documentation and the code, it seems that `options` that aren't `methods` are ignored? Why would adding `class_name` then throw an error?

Comment: @NicholasTulachI tried to answer your question, I updated my answer.

Comment: I think using `defaults` will work for my needs. Thanks!